# ASP.NET Validation Expressions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, expression

I've been through the MSDN chapter on this at least 50 times.

But I'll be darned if I can figure out how to write a simple validation expression that will accept any whole number greater than zero but less than 1,000.

I really wish they had more straight-forward documentation on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Have you tried the [Range Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx) with a `MinimumValue` of 1 and a `MaximumValue` of 999?

Comment: Can't. Specs are calling for a ValidatorCalloutExtender with a RegularExpressionValidator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regex expression for this would be something like this.  If you want to use the RegularExpressionValidator control

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)$
```